# The expense associated with DataBricks remains high despite opting for more budget-friendly backend instances(AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-databricks

Despite the availability of newer, more cost-effective AWS instances such as c6.size and c7.size, the use of these instances with Databricks results in higher prices compared to our current instances, c4.size and c5.size.

Cost of aws instances:

[image: cost of aws instances]

Cost of databricks DBU:
[image: cost of databricks DBU]
attached screenshots for reference

Even if I opt for cost-effective instances, the Databricks Unit (DBU) pricing remains higher for those instances. I would like to understand why it is like that.

Apologies if you feel this as a dumb question.

Expectation is that what is the cost criteria despite using the cost-effective one's.

Comment: databricks has its own cost. You'd have to ask them why their pricing is like that.

Comment: That pricing page _might_ include the cost of the EC2 instance, plus the extra charge that Databricks includes for its service. Databricks normally runs Compute clusters in your own cloud account (eg AWS) which means that your cloud provider will charge you for the instance, in which case the cost shown _might_ just be the Databricks cost, or it might be the combined cost of Databricks + cloud compute. The Databricks pricing is confusing, eh!